# SSL client Certificate windows

Tags: authentication, iis, ssl, certificate, offline

I need to make my iis authentication via client certificate offline. My iis don't have online enrollment. It need to be done offline. I configured SSL in IIS. I managed to create csr file locally manually  and sent to CA enrollment server i was able to issue certificate. I exported cer and imported in my client machine but while accessing iis application it is not using my certificate i am getting "HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden: SSL client certificate is required." how to solve it. Can somebody help me with step by procedures. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check in IIS.
Go to Website->SSL Settings

Do accept it in place of require and it will work for you.